# When are user event scripts triggered by Suitelets?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am debugging a sporadic "record has changed" error on the Sales Order record. The record has several different forms of scripting acting on it - there is a User Event script which calls a Suitelet, and a Workflow that in some cases will run a Workflow Script that calls another Suitelet. Each of the Suitelets makes multiple record submissions and loads. I didn't build this automation and am trying to understand how the operations chain together.

The question I am hung up on is whether the User Event script is being triggered after the Suitelet after every one of the submits, or only after the final submission of the Suitelet. If the user event script is being triggered after every submit, does execution of the Suitelet hold until the user event script has finished running, or does the User Event script and the remainder of the Suitelet run synchronously?

Comment: I've received this error when running concurrent restlets. The first one to call `record.save()` wins, and the second one fails with the error. Look for situations where more than one process is updating a record at the same time. For example, when two handlers are subscribed to the same event.

Comment: Thanks for this Josh, is there any easy way to identify when multiple handlers are subscribed to the same event? The way I have been doing this is using Scripted Records to identify all the scripts and workflows etc. associated with the record type and then going through them all, which is error prone and onerous

Comment: Sorry but I cannot be of much help there. I do not know. What I would recommend is that you "linearize" the process, which is a fancy way of saying, stop doing things concurrently, and instead, do them one at a time, in order. Have one thing do some work, complete, hand off to the next thing. You can have concurrent subscribers but each subscriber checks record state on load and only continues if it is its turn to run. Each handler updates the shared state to signal to later ones that it is done.

Comment: For anyone else discovering this, Netsuite support told me you cannot call a Suitelet (or make any other http request) in a workflow action step. It will halt the workflow. This wasn't the cause of the record has changed event.